# POSTで送ったデータをpythonのcgi.FieldStrageで受け取れない

Tags: python, http

ブラウザから送られてきたPOSTのフォームデータをcgi.FieldStorage()として、受け取ろうとするのですが、
FieldStorage(None, None, [])
になってしまいます。どうすればいいのでしょうか?

htmlは

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>data Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create</h1>
    <form action="/post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="name">name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" id="age" name="age" min="0" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" id="fileselector" name="file">
        </div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="送信"></div>
    </form>

    <br>
    <div><a href="/">Back to top</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

serverは

```
import http.server
import cgi

class handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print(cgi.FieldStorage()) # FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

というふうになっています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なぜBaseHTTPRequestHandlerでがんばっているのか、という疑問はありますが、以下のようにすれば取得出来ます。

```
import http.server
import cgi
import os

class handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST'
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(self.rfile, self.headers)
```